# Oracle SQL assign alternative values to each value and order

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query that looks similar to this:

```
SELECT num
FROM table1
ORDER BY num
```

For each `num` there is corresponding string `str` that is not stored in the database.  `str` is known only by my program.  It's not feasible to put the `str` in the database itself.

I would like to associate each `num` with a `str` and then order by `str`.  I need some sort of key/value association.  How would I do this?

Comment: if you want the database to sort your data it will need to know the num/str association. you could construct a decode to order your output by like `decode (num,1,'one',2,'two',3,'three',4,'four',5,'five','other')` and sort by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always feasible to put something like this in the database... in your case you're looking for a [simple case expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS256) though:

```
select num
     , case num
            when 1 then 'blah'
            when 2 then 'blah blah'
            when 3 then 'blah blah blah'
            else '...'
       end as str
  from table1
 order by num
```

If you want to do something more complex you can use the searched case:

```
select num
     , case when num = 1 then 'blah'
            when num = 2 then 'blah blah'
            when num = 3 then 'blah blah blah'
            else '...'
       end as str
  from table1
 order by num
```